# how to create separate column template in Kendo-UI grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I begin to use Kendo-UI in my project, I want one of my column show an image button and a field, similar with 'Contact Name' in documentation [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index).Then I was checking the documentation, and got the code as below.

```html
columns: [{
                    template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
                                    "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
                                "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
                    field: "ContactName",
                    title: "Contact Name",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "ContactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }, {
                    field: "CompanyName",
                    title: "Company Name"
                }, {
                    field: "Country",
                    width: 150
                }]
```

I don't think write html in the template directly is a good way, especially with a very complex template. Then I found another solution from the documentation.

```
"template": "kendo.template($('comments-template').html())"
```

This is more sensible in my scenario. But I'm very confused where to define the template is better. I also use AngularJS. Should I create a new file to write the template or any other place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`columns.template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) property expects a string or a function that returns a string. You can either use a `<script>` tag in the HTML markup...

```
<script id="script-template-id" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="myClass">#: FieldName #</div>
</script>

...

<script>
// ...

columns: [{
    title: "My Template Column",
    template: $('#script-template-id').html()
}]

// ...
</script>
```

... or use a string variable that is defined wherever you prefer, including an external JavaScript file (given that it will be registered early enough for the variable to be available):

```
var templateStringVariable = '<div class="myClass">#: FieldName #</div>';

// ...

columns: [{
    title: "My Template Column",
    template: templateStringVariable
}]
```

Note that this syntax will not work, as the JavaScript code itself is stringified:

```
"template": "kendo.template($('comments-template').html())"
```